# Good Assembly Language Debuggers for Linux?

Tags: linux, debugging, assembly

I'm currently working on some straight up assembly code on Ubunutu. I was wondering what my options are as far as debuggers go for just assembly code. Somethings with a GUI would be preferable.

Comment: https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger, edb is a cross platform AArch32/x86/x86-64 debugger. It was inspired by Ollydbg.

Comment: This question is not going to stir up a lot of debate, whether which is the most decent debugger on Linux. Actually the question is, is there a decent assembly  debugger and the answer is no. These question should be allowed in stack overflow, and the question should be not be shot down by bean counters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try DDD
http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/

Answer (score 1):

IDA Pro.

I love this program, I keep finding new features in it.

Comment: does this come in a version for linux. I only saw a .exe download.

Comment: @themaestro I was surprised, too, that this DOES come in a Linux and Mac version. I had thought it was Windows only at one time.

Comment: Is there a free non-commercial-use version for Mac or Linux?

Answer (score 1):

I only know about [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). If you really need a GUI try [Insight](http://sourceware.org/insight/faq.php) which is supposed to be a GUI for gdb. I haven't tired Insight personally yet.

Comment: I'd have to agree with you on GDB, but disagree on the GUI. GDB is a godly program if you can learn the command line interface. Regardless, you still get an upvote.

Comment: @Alex Hart well I don't really use any GUI when it comes to such things but I thought I might point him to the only one I've heard about.